# How to adjust ZXing on windows phone store app 8.1 camera (MediaCapture) preview size (full screen)?

Tags: windows-runtime, zxing

My project here:(https://github.com/79144876/ZXingStoreApp)
I have add zxing on my windows phone 8.1 project.The Zxing library here:(https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Clients/WindowsRTDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs)
But the preview size does not full screen.So,Anybody who knows how to change the preview size ?
And i have SetResolution,but still not full screen.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my code I do this

```
_capture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
_capture.SetPreviewMirroring(true);
CaptureView.Source = _capture;
CaptureView.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
```

In your case replace CaptureView to VideoCapture

But for now zxing for universal apps work terrible. MediaCapture not good choice to get data from camera :(